# On Removing index.php from URL, POST request is not working from RESTful API in Codeigniter3

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, restful-url

I removed Codeigniter's default index.php from the URL, I've tried the `.htaccess` method. It worked fine with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But there is an issue, when I send POST request from Android volley/Restful API, that `.htaccess` file redirect URL's index.php and all the data in POST request is lost. I've tried some other `.htaccess` configuration, but nothing is helping me out.
Can I get POST data on server side even when there is redirect in `.htaccsss`?

**EDITS**

I'm trying to send data to `http://192.168.1.52/getAllData`. With the above-mentioned `.htaccess`. On removing the code in `.htaccess`, the actual URL will be `http://192.168.1.52/index.php/getAllData` and it worked fine. After debugging my application, I've found that when my POST request reaches the server, the code in `.htaccess` file redirect the link, which results in losing the POST data on that URL without index.php

**EDIT END HERE**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention FROM which url  TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect; that will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: There is no redirect happening in the code shown here. Do you have some PHP code doing this redirect from `/index.php/getAllData` to `/getAllData` ?

Comment: Redirect is in `.htaccess`, see the last line of my given `.htaccess` code

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is, sending parameter to index.php(which should be something like: `index.php?param=value_here` where param could be anything you want to access by your index.php, if this is the case then have your .htaccess Rules file in following manner.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my issue is with the POST request, not the GET request. This redirect flushes out the data on the link.

Comment: @TayyabHayat, ok, could you please do give sample of url of GET and POST requests that will help me to understand what's going on here, cheers.

Comment: Okay, `https://example.com/getAllData` this is my main URL which is used as submit link, it has POST format of data, when this link come to server with post data, .htaccess rebuild URL with index.php, this process remove my data packet from actual link. But GET request working fine, because GET data is in the URL

Comment: @TayyabHayat, Could you please do provide details of GET and POST sample URLs so that I could understand it more, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change `.htaccess`

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

check your `application/config/config.php` file config.php `$config['index_page'] = '';`